# Delete doc when macro finishes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word 2007 docm file that I send to users as an email attachment to let them update files. The macros download files from a server and install them correctly - as opposed to sending the files as email attachments and trusting users to get it right. I'd use a VBScript file instead, but I'm not allowed to send that in an email.

I would like to delete this document from the user's computer when the macro finishes. But the doc is still open and the macro still running when it hits any Kill or FSO.FileDelete command.

edit: found a way to have the Word macro create and launch a VBScript, which fires after the doc closes and deletes the doc and the script.

Answer (score 2):

Late reply, I know.

Another way to achieve this for people not familiar with VBScripts might be to put something like this at the end of the macro:

```
Sub DeleteCurrentDoc()

Dim Doc1 As Document
Dim Doc2 As Document
Dim deletepath As String

'While the document you want to delete is open and is the current 'Active Document'
Set Doc1 = ActiveDocument

'get path of this document to delete it later
deletepath = Doc1.FullName

'Add a new temporary blank document
Set Doc2 = Documents.Add

'Close the document we are going to delete
Doc1.Close False

'Delete it
Kill (deletepath)

'Clear away the temp doc we created
Doc2.Close False

'Tidy up and close Word (Optional Line, delete if necessary)
Application.Quit

End Sub
```

EDIT: An even lighter way (Tested on Word 2013):

```
Sub DeleteCurrentDoc()

Dim deletepath As String

'get path of this document to delete it later
deletepath = ActiveDocument.FullName

'Close the document we are going to delete (Word should remain Open
ActiveDocument.Close False

'Delete it
Kill (deletepath)

'Tidy up and close Word (Optional Line, delete if necessary)
Application.Quit

End Sub
```