# Can't Close and Delete Open MSWord 2010 Document (ActiveDocument.Close prevents Kill command from running.)

Tags: ms-word

I'm trying to close the open word document and delete it as part of my DocumentBeforeClose event. I keep running across the following code in my searches (+/- some error trapping statements):

```
Dim Killfile As String
Killfile = Dir$(ActiveDocument.FullName)
   If Len(Dir$(Killfile)) > 0 Then
      SetAttr Killfile, vbNormal
      ActiveDocument.Close False
      Kill Killfile
   End if
```

I've found similar code (well, frankly almost identical code) in several places, and everyone seems to confirm that it works, but I cannot get it to run correctly in my own attempts, regardless of what module I have the code in. When run, the document always closes, but the code also stops there and never gets to the Kill command. In theory the instance of Word is supposed to keep running the script once the document closes; in my case the instance is open, but there's nothing running anymore at that point. Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

If it's helpful, in another version of the code I'm working with I have a Do While loop going through a directory and deleting documents containing "*temp.doc*" in the name. That code has no trouble running through and deleting closed files, but also will not delete the active/open document after closing.

Is this something I need to place in the Normal module in order for it to work? (Would reeeaally like to avoid that if possible). Thanks for any help!

Editing to add the top few relevant Search Results from Googling "MSWord VBA Delete Open Document":

- http://word.tips.net/T001346_Deleting_the_Open_Document_File.html
- http://geekgirls.com/2010/02/deleting-an-open-document-in-microsoft-word/
- [Delete doc when macro finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679118/delete-doc-when-macro-finishes)

Again, the unifying factor appears to be:

```
Activedocument.close
Kill WhateverOpenFile
```

...which just plain doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: DocumentBEFOREClose executes while the document is still open. An open file cannot be deleted. Unfortunately, Word doesn't have an "after close" event. But you might try with a WindowActivate or WindowDeactivate event. Perhaps have BeforeClose set a "global" that the other event checks and also store the document name. If it's set, check whether the Document is truly not still part of the Documents collection (because Close can be cancelled). If not, then run the Kill.

Comment: Hi Cindy! I liked your suggestions about trying to couple a global variable with WindowDeactivate, but I still was not able to get this code to run after the document closes (WindowDeactivate runs before the document closes as well, and if I use activedocument.close there I still don't make it to the kill command.) I have all but given up on having this run successfully; as it stands I'm putting the kill loop in the DocumentOpen event so that it runs "cleanup" in the target directory each time the document is opened, which will work sufficiently for my needs.

Comment: But the question that still remains for me is that I don't understand how people are getting this code to work for them, as it apparently seems to be the agreed upon solution to accomplish the task. Is it that I HAVE to place the code in the Normal module for MSWord? Unless I'm misreading I've never seen that requirement in conjunction with the code snippet. Is it something version specific (2010 vs 2013?)  Pretty puzzling.

Comment: Could you paste a couple of links to the full code in the DocumentBeforeClose event? All the discussions I've ever seen have used DocumentOpen... You don't mention whether you tried WindowActivate? I can also imagine looping in that event with a Windows API call to check when the file is finally released by Word (but don't have code for it).

Comment: Edited my original post with a few links, as requested! Thanks for sticking with me here.

Comment: Thank you. If you look carefully, not one of the links has the code in the DocumentBeforeClose event. It's a macro that first closes the document, then deletes it. Your problem is calling the code during the event - when the event executes that document is not closed.